# How to allow access to files for all sites while maintaining htaccess redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to keep the redirect rule. but I don't want to have to add site by site so that they can display the image. how can i change this rule so that it can do this trick? thanks in advance. Any help is welcome :)

actual htaccess

```
<Files ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Files>
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)fbclid=
    RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com [NC] 
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook,com/.*$ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook,com/ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://externalsite,com/ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://externalsite2,com/ [NC] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com.*$ [NC] 
     
    
    RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://mysite,com [NC,R,L]
    
    
    
    
    <IfModule mod_php4.c>
      php_value engine off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
      php_value engine off
    </IfModule>
    
    <Files ~ "\.((php[0-9]?)|p?html?|pl|sh|java|cpp|c|h|js|rc)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    </Files>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You will need to invest time to revise it, use the "edit" link below your question for that. What is it you actually want to achieve? Because unlike suggested in the question your code does _not_ have any redirection implemented at all. There is one rewriting rule, but that one is _not_ specific to a certain domain  or host name again. So it is unclear what your actual issue is and what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Your "redirect rule" is a _hotlink protection_ script that allows specific sites access. You need to explicitly identify each site in your rule in order to grant access to that site, (How else do _you_ identify the referring site?) However, if there is a _pattern_ to the domain names/URLs that you wish to allow access then you could possibly create a "catch-all" rule. But there is nothing to suggest that this is the case from what you've posted.

Comment: "allow access to files for all sites" - please define "all sites". If you literally mean "all sites" then you do need to remove that rule altogether. (?)

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for reply. Yes I wanted to give full access to other sites to incorporate my content. but without removing the rule in which the user accessing the final file via the url example: (mysite.com/uploads/test.gif) he continues to be redirected to the main url
RewriteRule \. (Jpg | jpeg | png | gif) $ https: // mysite, with [NC, R, L]

Comment: @MrWhite ould you help me with this rule to release everything just by redirecting if you access the file directly at mysite.com/uploads/test.gif

I'm a beginner and I'm having difficulties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com [NC] 
>     
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook,com/.*$ [NC] 
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.facebook,com/ [NC] 
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://externalsite,com/ [NC] 
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://externalsite2,com/ [NC] 
>     RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://mysite,com.*$ [NC] 
>      
>     
>     RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://mysite,com [NC,R,L]
> ```

> I wanted to give full access to other sites to incorporate my content ... redirecting if you access the file directly at `example.com/uploads/test.gif`

If you simply want to block *direct* access (in which case the `Referer` header is empty) and allow all other sites to link to your images (basically the opposite of "hotlink protection") then you can replace the above rule (that redirects such requests to the root) with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ https://example.com/ [NC,R,L]
```

This redirects all *direct* requests to the root / home page.

(You had erroneous commas `,` in your original directives that would have prevented this from working?!)

HOWEVER, basing this redirect on the HTTP `Referer` is unreliable - you will get false positives. The `Referer` is sent by the browser - so the user can control (and suppress) what is sent. The website that is linking to you can also set a referrer-policy that suppresses the HTTP `Referer` being sent - so all requests from some sites might look like direct requests anyway and end up being blocked. There is no way around this.

Comment: Sorry, fixed typo.... - should be `HTTP_REFERER`, not `HTTP_HOST`, in the `RewriteCond` directive!

Comment: it is like this


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond% {QUERY_STRING} (?: ^ | &) Fbclid =
RewriteRule ^ / [L, R = permanent]



RewriteCond% {HTTP_HOST} ^ $
RewriteRule \. (Jpg | jpeg | png) $ https://mysite..com/ [NC, R, L]

but is not doing the redirect

Comment: Yes, but see my comment/correction above - should be `HTTP_REFERER`, not `HTTP_HOST`! (That was just muscle memory messing up my typing! ;)